# Return max value with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to get maximal value from the table and return it to backend method, but I did this in a wrong way. At present time I have something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [firstProcedure]
    @_maxEntityId VARCHAR(3) OUTPUT
BEGIN
    SET @_maxEntityId = 'SELECT MAX(entityId) FROM TableFrom'
    PRINT @_maxEntityId
    RETURN (@_maxEntityId)
END
```

Trying to print `@_maxEntityId` but didn't see anything.

Comment: You have set @_maxEntityId to the string 'select max(...)'. You should set it to  SET @_maxEntityId = (select max(entityId) from TableFrom)

Comment: @less, okay, why it doesn't print any results?? only `Commands completed successfully.`

Comment: It will print out the 3 first characters 'sel'

Comment: No, do as you said and have again `Commands completed successfully.`

Comment: Might you just have run the create procedure script? You need to exectue the stored procedure.

Comment: looks like that,I am really bad in this.
Can you tell me please how can I see output value if it don't want to print anything??

Comment: execute it and you will get the value :-)

Comment: trying to do it in this way 
    `EXECUTE [firstProcedure] 
 N'1979' 
 DECLARE @_max VARCHAR(4)
 print @_max ` and have an empty output

Comment: @less all works, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [firstProcedure]
    @maxEntityId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @maxEntityId = MAX(entityId) 
    FROM
        TableFrom    
    PRINT @maxEntityId

    RETURN (@maxEntityId)
END
```

Comment: if doing as you offering - have this message `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to return result because the parameter is OUTPUT already. SP should be like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [firstProcedure]
    @maxEntityId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @maxEntityId = MAX(entityId) 
    FROM
        TableFrom        
END
```

Here is to invoke the SP

```
DECLARE 
        @maxEntityId INT

EXEC    [firstProcedure]
        @firstProcedure= @firstProcedureOUTPUT

SELECT  @firstProcedureas N'@firstProcedure'
```